# How to install a SSL certificate on Azure?

Tags: azure, ssl

I am trying to install an SSL cert on my Azure instance. I followed this tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

However, when I deploy the package on to the staging instance it does not start up. And we can't retrieve detailed bug, and can't connect remotely to that instance.

I am not sure what else can be done? Please help?